# Problems with Google Drive total quota info for users who bought additional storage

Tags: google-drive-api

For my application I need calculate available storage for each user.
I using About API(https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get) and following formula:

```
Free storage = (quotaBytesTotal - quotaBytesUsed)
```

It works well, except users without Extra storage. For such users quotaBytesUsed is more than quotaBytesTotal:

```
  {"kind"=>"drive#user", "displayName"=>"D B", "isAuthenticatedUser"=>true},
 "quotaBytesTotal"=>"5368709120",
 "quotaBytesUsed"=>"26843545600",
 "quotaBytesUsedAggregate"=>"26843545600",
 "quotaBytesUsedInTrash"=>"0",
 "largestChangeId"=>"363004",
```

Is this API bug? 
How I can calculate free storage for such users?

Comment: This does look like a bug. I will check and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce this, does it happen for all users with extra quota? Might there be a time delay between the user buying quota and the value updating?

Comment: I found this issue for few users from the same domain. I can't provide information about domain name here. Is there any way how we can chat securely?

Comment: Ali Afshar, can you help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found reason of issue.
Our user bought +20GB of extra storage. He had 25GB of quota and almost all 25GB were used.
Last month payment subscription (for extra storage) was cancelled, and quota for this user was reduced to 5GB.

This is why `quotaBytesUsed > quotaBytesTotal`